# Flutter : how to achieve expansion of a customPainter widget in vertical (height) direction

Tags: dart, flutter

I draw a custom widget with a customPainter Widget but i can't expanded it in a column widget. I had seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875334/how-to-achieve-expansion-of-a-widget-in-both-vertical-height-and-horizontal-w?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but even with `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` i had the problem. When i use an `Expanded` widget instead of `Flexible` widget i got a compilation error.
As you can see widget don't care about the custom widget and draw the bottom card text on the customPaint.

The CardView widget I am trying to expand extends CustomPaint, with no children, everything is painted using a CustomPainter on canvas, in the `CustomPainter.paint(canvas, size)`.

In `paint(canvas, size)` method when i print the `size.height` i get 0.0, that explain why the text bottom is printed on the widget.

Widget code :

```
   class CardViewState extends State<CardView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Text(
            "CARD TOP",
            //widget.card.name,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
        new Flexible(
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: new CardPainter(widget.card, widget.numbers),
          ),
        ),
        new Padding(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new Text(
            "CARD BOTTOM",
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[result looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zClPs.png)

What do I need to change to achieve the height expansion as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `CustomPaint` takes the size of its child, if it has one. As you have none, you get a height of zero. If you are happy for the `CustomPaint` to fill the space between the two padded texts, use `Expanded` instead of `Flexible`.

It looks like your bingo card may look best with a fixed height, in which case you could used `SizedBox` with just a height as the parent.

Comment: Yes i know but if i use an Expanded i can't used my widget in a ListView. For the SizedBox, my cardView height is compute from the paint's width, so i could define my width by default but i need the widget width. I can't doing a context.size.width in the build method.

Comment: If you drawing has a fixed aspect ratio, you could experiment with an AspectRatio inside the Expanded or vice versa to limit the height based on the width.

Comment: Actually, just try replacing Flexible with AspectRatio with 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for me with AspectRatio Widget

Comment: Using Expanded does not work for me. Using AspecRatio however works like charm